# Does it make sense to apply a chi-squared test on a contingency table when the whole population has been surveyed?

Tags: sampling, chi-squared-test

As I understand it, one of the main goal of the chi-squared test on a contingency table is to determine if the link between lines and columns of the table is "more" than the sampling bias and the random fluctuations it can generate.

So my question is : if a contingency table contains the whole surveyed population, there is no more sampling bias. So does it make sense to apply a chi-squared test on this table, or do we just have to look at line and column percentages without worrying to test against the null hypothesis ?

Thanks in advance for any hints !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the whole population of interest has been surveyed, then there's really no statistical analysis to do - any differences you see *are* differences in the population by definition.

Comment: I would amend @EpiGrad 's answer to say there are no *inferential* statistics to be done. You can certainly do descriptive statistics.

Comment: There is a theory in survey sampling of superpopulation models. If you assume that the population is a sample from a superpopulation then I think there is a way to do statistical inference.  But to apply such a model would mean that you are interested in answering a different question than whether or not the proportions are different in this given population.

Comment: Here is a link to a nice introductory article on superpopulation models [this](http://people.umass.edu/~cluster/ed/outline/c99ed8.PDF)